# How to Store Azure VM Snapshot from one subscription into an RG of another subscription via PS Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I am taking OS and Data disk Snapshots of VM's part of an array of declared subscriptions, but want to store it in an RG which is part some other subscription (in the same tenant).
Within foreach loop if we try to do Set-AzContext to that other subscription, it doesn't work.

Comment: PS code-:
foreach($subscID in $subscIDs){
$vms=get-azvm
}

'looking into VMs'
foreach ($vm in $vms){
Set-azcontext -subscriptionId $subscID
$snap= new-azsnapshot $RG`
}

Answer (score 0):

When working with multiple subscription swapping in Azure, you can use `set-AZcontext` as you previously did. However, it may not always work due to a conflict. In that case, store the subscription in a context variable within the foreach loop and modify `set-AZcontext` by adding `-context`parameter to the command as shown below.

```
$conext = get-azcontext
set-Azcontext -context $context
```

I tried the below script in my environment to move snapshots from one to another without using the context parameter, but it worked as expected.

Verify the `foreach` loop once and run the below script. If still the issue persists in your environment, Use the `context` as given above.

```
$targetSubscriptionID = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId <tagetsubscription> //You can also use get-azcontext 
$vms = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup> -Name "vm"
foreach ($vm in $vms) {                                                                                                    
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $vm.subscriptionID #source subscription
$snaps = Get-AzSnapshot -snapShotName "newlatestsnap" -ResourceGroupName <sourceresourcegroup>
Set-AzContext -subscription $targetSubscriptionID
$snapshotID =  $snaps.id
Move-AzResource -ResourceId $snapshotId -DestinationResourceGroupName <destinationRG> -DestinationSubscriptionId <targetsubscriptionID>
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @jahnavi,
I tried to switch the context both the ways but it didnt worked in my runbook within the for each loop as it is again refering back to the original subscription in loop or not able to switch to the target subscription at all. Is there any way I can connect with you to show you, would be very helpful then.

Comment: Can you share the error image which you are getting..@SahilWadehra